# Setting the last date collected to be a Monday

Tags: r, quantmod

I can download a data set using Quantmod

```
library(quantmod)
getSymbols("SPY", from="2013-01-01", to=Sys.Date())
chartSeries(SPY)
```

I would like the last data to be collected to be always on a Monday (so if I collect data on say Thursday, the Tuesday,Wednesday and Thursday data points will be filtered out). Is there a  way to do this.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

replace your `to=Sys.Date()` with `to=(Sys.Date()-c(6:0))[format((Sys.Date()-c(6:0)),"%w")=="1"]`